# how to fix "CannotResolveClassException: node" Error in JMETER 5.5, suggest please

Tags: java, jmeter

## how to fix "CannotResolveClassException: node" Error in JMETER 5.5, suggest please .

## in some of the JMX files getting this error though able to open and work on other files.

Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: node

Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:456) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:429) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:129) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) ~[?:?]
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: node
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:97) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:135) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1421) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1399) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1284) ~[xstream-1.4.19.jar:1.4.19]
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:446) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
... 20 more
2023-12-15 20:02:57,730 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\diwgupta\Scripts\IMS_32260.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: node

updated the java class path

Comment: Check [ask] and [mcve]. As is, this is just an error dump, not a question. Total garbage.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to open a file created by either very old version of JMeter or 3rd-party software like [Badboy](https://www.qatestingtools.com/testing-tool/badboy).

Try using one of the previous JMeter versions which are available at [archives page](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/jmeter/binaries/). Once done you will be able to either save it incrementally (pay attention to Incompatible Changes from [JMeter Changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) for each respective version) or just replay it and record the execution using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690665233-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder), the latter one can take care of correlation.